# Jmeter text format to "add from clipboard"

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, notepad++, notepad

I need to paste a lot of values in my jmeter HTTP Request and I want paste from a notepad++, notepad... I knnow to separate with "=" names and values but how can I separate rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line separator should be the row separator.

Regarding column separator, it can also sometimes be space or tab.
Did you try it ?

Comment: Yes, It was my fault, I had all lines with a tab and Jmeter doesn't detect correctly the line separator. Thank you!